# Nested setTimeouts with the same name , any repercussions doing this ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was just going through the source code of typed.js and basically the main function in this plugin uses a design pattern of multiple setTimeout's nested inside one another, Have a look at the code:

```
self.timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    // check for an escape character before a pause value
    // format: \^\d+ .. eg: ^1000 .. should be able to print the ^ too using ^^
    // single ^ are removed from string
    var charPause = 0;
    var substr = curString.substr(curStrPos);
    if (substr.charAt(0) === '^') {
        var skip = 1; // skip atleast 1
        if (/^\^\d+/.test(substr)) {
            substr = /\d+/.exec(substr)[0];
            skip += substr.length;
            charPause = parseInt(substr);
        }

        // strip out the escape character and pause value so they're not printed
        curString = curString.substring(0, curStrPos);
    }

    if (self.contentType === 'html') {
        // skip over html tags while typing
        var curChar = curString.substr(curStrPos).charAt(0);
        if (curChar === '<' || curChar === '&') {
            var tag = '';
            var endTag = '';
            if (curChar === '<') {
                endTag = '>';
            } else {
                endTag = ';';
            }
            while (curString.substr(curStrPos).charAt(0) !== endTag) {
                tag += curString.substr(curStrPos).charAt(0);
                curStrPos++;
            }
            curStrPos++;
            tag += endTag;
        }
    }

    // timeout for any pause after a character
    self.timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        if (curStrPos === curString.length) {
            // fires callback function
            self.options.onStringTyped(self.arrayPos);

            // is this the final string
            if (self.arrayPos === self.strings.length - 1) {
                // animation that occurs on the last typed string
                self.options.callback();

                self.curLoop++;

                // quit if we wont loop back
                if (self.loop === false || self.curLoop === self.loopCount)
                    return;
            }

            self.timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                self.backspace(curString, curStrPos);
            }, self.backDelay);
        } else {

            /* call before functions if applicable */
            if (curStrPos === 0)
                self.options.preStringTyped(self.arrayPos);

            // start typing each new char into existing string
            // curString: arg, self.el.html: original text inside element
            var nextString = curString.substr(0, curStrPos + 1);
            if (self.attr) {
                self.el.attr(self.attr, nextString);
            } else {
                if (self.isInput) {
                    self.el.val(nextString);
                } else if (self.contentType === 'html') {
                    self.el.html(nextString);
                } else {
                    self.el.text(nextString);
                }
            }

            // add characters one by one
            curStrPos++;
            // loop the function
            self.typewrite(curString, curStrPos);
        }
        // end of character pause
    }, charPause);

    // humanized value for typing
}, humanize);
```

I don't have a problem understanding the code above, but i am a bit skeptical about the usage of multiple setTimeouts inside each other **WITH THE SAME NAME** I.E.

```
self.timeout
```

Is this something ok to do ? are there any repercussions of using setTimeouts nested inside each other ? or is this kind of a coding approach totally fine. I had a big question mark in my mind when i actually saw the `setTimeouts` in the code with the same name.

**[CODE ON GIT](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/blob/master/js/typed.js#L149)**

Thank you.

Alex-z

Comment: I don't think technically there causes any issue... as timeout is called only once... once it is called there is no need to keep a reference to it.... but as a practice it could be confusing

Comment: You don't seem to be calling `clearTimeout` anywhere, so why are you capturing the return value in the first place?

Comment: The timeout handle is dumped when the timeout is called. It is a perfectly acceptable way of managing the handle. The handle is just a `Number` object.

Comment: @Blindman67, I am not quite understanding what you are saying !

Comment: @Quentin , what is i say `clearTimeout(self.timeout)` ? will all the timeouts clear ?

Comment: No, of course not. When you assign a value somewhere, you overwrite whatever was previously stored there.

Comment: @Quentin makes sense , thanks you !!

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem assigning multiple `setTimeout()` return values to the same variable `self.timeout`.

But you will lose the possibility to clear all previous timeouts with `clearTimeout()` as `self.timeout` got overwritten each time with the last `setTimeout()` return value.

However, in the specific code example you provided `clearTimeout()` is not used. So while missing its purpose, assigning the return value to the same variable `self.timeout` is also useless.